# como pegar dados de fora e adicionar em uma função ja existente em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um joguinho de dados mas quando quero colocar uma continha de pontos não estou conseguindo...

```
def get_dados():
  dado1 = int(input("Digite o número para o primeiro dado: "))
  dado2 = int(input("Digite o número para o segundo dado: "))
  return dado1, dado2
dado1, dado2 = get_dados()
```

## Aposta

```
def aposta(fichas):
  aposta = 0
  while(aposta >= 0):
      try:
        aposta = int(input("Digite sua aposta: "))
        if(aposta > 49 and aposta < 301):
          fichas -= aposta
          print("Suas fichas agora são: ", fichas)
          break
        else:
          print("Sua aposta deve ser maior ou igual a 50 e menor ou igual a 300!")
      except ValueError:
        print("\nDigite uma opção válida!")
aposta(fichas)

def jogarDados(dado1,dado2):
  primer_dado=random.randint(1,6)
  segund_dado=random.randint(1,6)
  print("Jogando os dados...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("...")
  print("O resultado dos dados foram:", primer_dado, "e", segund_dado)
  if (primer_dado == dado1 or segund_dado == dado2) or (primer_dado == dado2 or segund_dado == dado1):
    print("parabéns, você acertou sua aposta...")

    fichas=fichas+aposta+aposta
    print("suas fichas atuais são: ",fichas)
  else :
    print("perdeu a sua aposta")
    #print("infelizmenente você perdeu essa rodada, e junto com a rodada perdeu sua aposta... nao desista.. ainda da tempo")
jogarDados(dado1,dado2)
```

o código esta assim mas estou tendo dificuldade em especial nessa parte:

```
print("O resultado dos dados foram:", primer_dado, "e", segund_dado)
  if (primer_dado == dado1 or segund_dado == dado2) or (primer_dado == dado2 or segund_dado == dado1):
    print("parabéns, você acertou sua aposta...")

    fichas=fichas+aposta+aposta
    print("suas fichas atuais são: ",fichas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim, renomeie a função `aposta()` para `get_aposta()`, daí você poderá chamá-la assim:

```
aposta = get_aposta(fichas)
```

E quando for a vez de chamar a função `jogarDados()`, esta terá acesso de leitura ao conteúdo da variável "aposta" que foi definida anteriormente.